# FBA with LDAP shows account name not the User Given Name

Tags: forms-authentication, ldap

I have implemented FBA with LDAP. The people editor is resolving FBA users, but it shows the Account Name, not the Name.
e.g. , but I want name for that employee.

Here is the Membership provide which I used. same used in Web app, STS and CA..

<add name="ADSiteNCRMemberShipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="SiteNCRADConnectionString" enableSearchMethods="true" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard behaviour of the ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider. I do not believe that this can be changed. Wherever you require the current user to be shown on your masterpage etc you can simply reference the SPUser.Name property after authenticating.